# help with boot failure because of fstab entry

Tags: boot, raspbian

Machine: RaspberryPi 4; OS: Raspbian

SETUP: SD card for /boot and /root

USB-C SSD for data, partitioned into 1 NTFS for samba, 1 EXT4 for other data

SSH access only (and I don't have a micro HDMI so I can't connect to a monitor to see any boot errors)

I had a power outage and, upon the return of electricity, my rPI (4.0) won't boot properly.

I've localized the issue to the `fstab` line which (attempts to) mount the SSD/EXT4 partition. If i comment it out, the Pi boots properly. If I run `fstab` with the line, it hangs up and won't boot properly (I need to then manually edit the `fstab` file on the SD card on another machine to re comment-out the offending line).

I can re-mount the EXT4 partition manually and it works just fine. fstab entry is:

```
 PARTUUID=BLAHBLAH-02 /mnt/cloud ext4 default 0 0
```

(`BLAHBLAH-01` is the PARTUUID for the correctly-mounting NTFS partition)

Possible issues:

1. `fdisk` reports the ext mount as ID 7 | TYPE HPFS/NTFS/exFAT not EXT 4?
2. `blkid` reports the correct partition ID, but `lsblk` does not (it omits the -01 and -02)?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. my fstab entry had "default", but apparently correct syntax is "default**s**"

i corrected this and it appeared to boot up properly.

Comment: Add option "nofail" if you wan it to boot while the SSD is unplugged or non-responsive.